# NoMethodError in CarController#add undefined method `user_id=' for #<Car:0x71451d8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
NoMethodError in CarController#add

undefined method `user_id=' for #<Car:0x7160c70>
RAILS_ROOT: C:/Users/Jatinder/BitNami RubyStack projects/mercedes_mod 2
add.html (for adding car)
```

add.html in /views/car

```
<h1>Ask a Question or Discuss Your Car</h1>
<%= error_messages_for :car %>
<br>
<p>You can ask anything related to cars even if its not a Mercedes!</p>
<% form_for :car do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name, "Title of Question" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description, "Describe Your Question" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

def add in car_controller.rb:

```
def add 
      @title = "Ask a New Question"
    if request.post?
       @car = Car.new(params[:car])
       @car.user_id = User.logged_in(session).id
    if @car.save
        flash[:notice] = "Car #{@car.name} added!"
        redirect_to :controller => :car, :action => :index
      end
    end
  end
```

car.rb model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :subject
  validates_presence_of :name, :description
end
```

routes.rb

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.resources :car, :users => { :delete => :get }
  map.root :controller => "main"
  map.root :controller => "car", :action => "destroy"
end
```

create_cars migration:

```
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.interger :user_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :cars
  end
end
```

Comment: In the future can you please be more descriptive about your problem? I think its rude just to post all of your code at once and expect us to debug it. That said, can you tell us what other error you are getting after you corrected the typo in your migration? Try running rake db:drop and rake db:migrate and post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migration has a typo. You should have `t.integer`, not `t.interger` on your `:user_id`. Also, make sure to run `rake db:migrate` in your console before running your app.

Comment: I done the change and ran rake db:migrate still same error

Comment: Assuming that you had already run it before, you may need to run `rake db:migrate:redo` instead.

Comment: nope i have also ran that just now and it did migrate fully but still no go same error? @dmarkow

Answer (score 0):

Your migration is busted:

```
t.interger :user_id
```

You're looking for an **integer**.

Comment: I have changed it still no go